# AngularJS and SpringBoot secure communication

Tags: angularjs, spring, security, spring-boot, spring-security

I am wondering how to make simple and secure rest communication between my backend and frontend. I need to send some POST request's to my backend and somehow i need to secure that. This is simple app without any users accounts.

Comment: Use basic authentication or token like jwt implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Serve your app over HTTPS instead of HTTP. Any calls made from angularjs using `$http` will be secured, you don't have to do anything here.